# Trouble using hyperref and bibentry packages together

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, bibentry

I am getting an error when I use `hyperref` and `bibentry` packages together. The error is:

```
./Test.bbl:1: LaTeX Error: Command \BR@bibitem already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Pointing to `l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{2}`, which is, of course, the first line of the `Text.bbl` file.

`Test` is the name of my MWE file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pagebackref=true,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Look ma, inline bibtex entries:

\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{McCune:2015}\end{NoHyper}
\item \begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{Deshpande:2018aa}\end{NoHyper}
\end{itemize}

\section{And now for something completely different}
Lorem ipsum yada yada,
also see \citep{McCune:2015}, 
yada yada, and \citep{Deshpande:2018aa} too.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{testref}

\end{document}
```

The `testref.bib` file is the following:

```
@STRING{COMPSUR     = {ACM Comput. Surv.}}

@book{Deshpande:2018aa,
    Author = {Deshpande, Amol and Gupta, Amarnath},
    Date-Added = {2017-04-12 14:27:29 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-04-12 14:28:23 +0000},
    Note = {Forthcoming},
    Publisher = {ACM Books},
    Title = {Principles of Graph Data Management and Analytics},
    Year = {2018}}

@article{McCune:2015,
    Author = {McCune, Robert Ryan and Weninger, Tim and Madey, Greg},
    Journal = COMPSUR,
    Number = {2},
    Numpages = {39},
    Pages = {25:1--25:39},
    Title = {Thinking Like a Vertex: A Survey of Vertex-Centric Frameworks for Large-Scale Distributed Graph Processing},
    Url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2818185},
    Volume = {48},
    Year = {2015}}
```

Any suggestions of what I might be doing wrong? If I delete the hyperref package, things work. I did read articles here, but the suggested solutions do not help -- one was to wrap the `\bibentry` with `NoHyper` that I have in the MWE (in fact, the MWE is taken from one of those).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load `hyperref` after the other packages, see [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before) for excpetions.

```
\begin{filecontents}{testref.bib}
@STRING{COMPSUR     = {ACM Comput. Surv.}}

@book{Deshpande:2018aa,
    Author = {Deshpande, Amol and Gupta, Amarnath},
    Date-Added = {2017-04-12 14:27:29 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-04-12 14:28:23 +0000},
    Note = {Forthcoming},
    Publisher = {ACM Books},
    Title = {Principles of Graph Data Management and Analytics},
    Year = {2018}}

@article{McCune:2015,
    Author = {McCune, Robert Ryan and Weninger, Tim and Madey, Greg},
    Journal = COMPSUR,
    Number = {2},
    Numpages = {39},
    Pages = {25:1--25:39},
    Title = {Thinking Like a Vertex: A Survey of Vertex-Centric Frameworks for Large-Scale Distributed Graph Processing},
    Url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2818185},
    Volume = {48},
    Year = {2015}}

\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*
\usepackage[pagebackref=true,linktocpage]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Look ma, inline bibtex entries:
%
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{McCune:2015}\end{NoHyper}
\item \begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{Deshpande:2018aa}\end{NoHyper}
\end{itemize}

\section{And now for something completely different}
Lorem ipsum yada yada,
also see \citep{McCune:2015}, 
yada yada, and \citep{Deshpande:2018aa} too.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{testref}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!... I knew hyperref was finicky about order, but I did not think about this for some reason. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Loading hyperref after the other packages may not be enough. The [hyperref](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html) manual suggests the following workaround (change "database" with your own bib file):

```
  \makeatletter
  \let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem
  \makeatother

  \usepackage{bibentry}
  \usepackage{hyperref}

  \begin{document}

  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem
    \nobibliography{database}
  \endgroup
```